# Can't find why the if block not getting executed

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie in javascript, i've been following a youtube video of creating a simple project like booklist app using javascript the tutorial is very well explained but when i tried to do it myself i got stuck at one point i can't figure out what's happening

The project is basically about when i submit the details of the book it will be added to the table in the webpage, also it will stored in the local storage too. same like that i need to remove the details of the book from local storage when it is removed from the table.
[image]

Here is the code for setting up the class **Store** with methods **getBooks** for getting the books from the local storage, **addBook** for adding new book to local storage, **removeBook** for removing the book from local storage

```
class Store{
    static getBooks(){
        let books;
        if (localStorage.getItem('books') == null) {
            books = [];
        } else{
            books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'));
        }
        return books;
    }

    static addBook(Book) {
        const books = Store.getBooks();
        books.push(Book);
        localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
    }

    static removeBook(isbn){
        const books = Store.getBooks();
        books.forEach((book, index) => {
            if (book.isbn === isbn) {
                books.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });

        localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
    }
}
```

The methods getBooks and addBooks are working perfectly fine, but the **removeBook** method is not working in a way that i wanted.

Here is how i invoked the method,

```
document.querySelector('#book-list').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // Delete book from the table in interface
    UI.deleteBook(e.target);
   
    Store.removeBook(e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent);
});
```

`e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent` is getting the correct value i needed, so i did made the call to removeBook successfully but i can't pass through the **if** block inside the method

Here is my complete HTML script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Book List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootswatch@4.5.2/dist/yeti/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="undefined" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <h1 class="display-4 text-center">
        <i class="fas fa-book-open text-primary"></i> My<span class="text-primary">Book
        </Myspan>List</h1>
        <form class="book-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="author">Author</label>
                <input type="text" id="author" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="isbn">ISBN#</label>
                <input type="text" id="isbn" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Book" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        </form>
        <table class="table table-striped mt-5">
            <thead>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>ISBN</th>
                <th></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="book-list"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my complete javascript code,

```
class Book{
    constructor(title, author, isbn){
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
}


class UI{
    static displayBooks(){

        const books = Store.getBooks();

        books.forEach((book) => UI.addBookToList(book))
    }

    static addBookToList(book){
        const list = document.querySelector("#book-list");

        const row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.innerHTML = `
            <td> ${book.title} </td>
            <td> ${book.author} </td>
            <td> ${book.isbn} </td>
            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete">X</a></td>
        `;
        list.appendChild(row);
    }

    static deleteBook(el){
        if(el.classList.contains('delete')){
            el.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        }
    }

    static showAlert(message, className) {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = `alert alert-${className}`;
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        const container = document.querySelector('.container');
        const form = document.querySelector('.book-form');
        container.insertBefore(div, form);
        setTimeout(()=>
            document.querySelector('.alert').remove(),
            3000
        );
    }

    static clearFields() {
        document.querySelector('#title').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#author').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#isbn').value = '';
    }
}

class Store{
    static getBooks(){
        let books;
        if (localStorage.getItem('books') == null) {
            books = [];
        } else{
            books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'));
        }
        return books;
    }

    static addBook(Book) {
        const books = Store.getBooks();
        books.push(Book);
        localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
    }

    static removeBook(isbn){
        const books = Store.getBooks();
        books.forEach((book, index) => {
            if (book.isbn.toString() === isbn.toString()) {
                books.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });

        localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", UI.displayBooks());


document.querySelector('.book-form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    const title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
    const author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
    const isbn = document.querySelector('#isbn').value;

    if (title === '' || author === '' || isbn === '') {
        UI.showAlert("Please fill in all fileds", "danger");
    } else {
        const book = new Book(title, author, isbn);

        UI.addBookToList(book);
        Store.addBook(book);
        UI.clearFields();
        UI.showAlert("Succefully added", 'success');
    }
});

document.querySelector('#book-list').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    Store.removeBook(e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent);
    UI.deleteBook(e.target);
    UI.showAlert("Succefully removed", 'success');
});
```

I spent one and half hour to figure out what's wrong in the code but i still can't, I'm completely new to javascript.

Comment: `Store.getBook()` (in the first line of addBook) is not the same as `Store.getBooks()`.

Comment: are the `book.isbn` and `isbn` the same type? if not the `===` will return false

Comment: You can try `book.isbn.toString() === isbn.toString()` in your if statement

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica it was mistake that i made when i copied the code from my computer to this site. now i edited it.

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe yes, book.isbn and isbn are same type i checked it

Comment: If `UI.deleteBook(e.target);` really detaches the target node from the DOM, then `e.target.parentElement` will be a null reference. You should at least swap those two statements then. But without knowing what `UI` is, etc, ... impossible to tell.

Comment: @Kinglish i tried it now, but it still not working

Comment: @trincot i tried  swaping the methods now but it's not working. I edited the question with adding UI class now

Comment: Can you complete the code with sample data, HTML and actual call that fails, so that we don't have to guess, but just can reproduce the problem by running it?

Comment: Are you sure that the event is being called?

Comment: @RBarryYoung yes i'm sure it's being called, i checked it.

Comment: @trincot i updated my question  with adding my html and javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your HTML you pad the book ISBN (and other fields) with spaces:

```
    row.innerHTML = `
        <td> ${book.title} </td>
        <td> ${book.author} </td>
        <td> ${book.isbn} </td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete">X</a></td>
    `;
```

This means that the `textContent` of those `td` elements will *not* match with the properties of your `book` object. Either trim what you get from `textContent`, or just remove those spaces from your HTML:

```
    row.innerHTML = `
        <td>${book.title}</td>
        <td>${book.author}</td>
        <td>${book.isbn}</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete">X</a></td>
    `;
```

If your goal was to give these texts a bit of margin, then do that with CSS styling instead.

There are also 2 other issues I bumped into:

- Your HTML has `</Myspan>`, which should be `</span>`.
- You don't correctly set the handler for the `DOMContentLoaded` event. The argument should be a function, but you actually *execute* a function instead (immediately). So remove the parentheses at the end:

  ```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", UI.displayBooks);
  ```